# Implementation of the Control of a Quadrotor, as taught in Aerial Robotics in Coursera

Tags: quadcopter, control, motor, microcontroller

I completed the course of Aerial Robotics in Coursera and I want to implement what I learned in a real quadrotor. The thing is that when I see the equations given like this:
[image]
For the sake of the argument let's assume I have implemented the PD Controllers and every moment I find u1 (the sum of the forces applied to the quadrotor) and u2 (the sum of the moments applied to the quadrotor). I then ask myself: How can I find what force and moment should specifically each one of the motors produce? And here I am stuck as I can't find an answer.Could anyone help?

Comment: are you planning on having a physical quadrotor which you are controlling?

Comment: yeap, I do have one and I'm controling it with Arduino for now

Comment: i recommend getting a purpose built autopilot. it'll save a lot of headaches

Comment: Yeah but the thing is that the purpose of the drone is not to control it with PID

Comment: But to experiment on nonlinear control

Comment: you can buy autopilots with open source software. this takes care of all the other problems of autopilot design and gives you a framework within which you can develop nonlinear controllers. I  recommend the pixhawk autopilot. Unless you have a team of grad students working on building autopilot software,  you are unlikely to succeeded. Look into the pixhawk software. It will save a lot of head aches

Comment: Yes,but I don't have so much money...

Comment: Haha the funny fact is that I am undergrad!

Comment: you can get stuff cheaper than a pixhawk. but do not try to do this with an arduino. it is a fool's errand.

Comment: What would you suggest for example?

Comment: ive only worked with the pixhawk. google open source quadrotor autopilot.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* M.Karam. On stack exchange, it is better to edit your question to add information requested in comments, rather than adding more comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. If all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied up (deleted).

Comment: Also, on stack exchange, comments are not intended for extended discussions, for that use [chat]. Comments should be considered ephemeral, any comment which no longer actively helps to improve a question or answer may be deleted at any time to *tidy up* a post.

Comment: Please consider transcribing the relevant formulae in the image into MathJax expressions in your question, as the image is difficult to read as is. On *Robotics* we are fortunate enough to have MathJax support enabled, allowing you to easily create subscripts, superscripts, fractions, square roots, greek letters and more. This allows you to add both inline and block element mathematical expressions in *robotics* questions and answers. For a quick tutorial, take a look at [How can I format mathematical expressions here, using MathJax?](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/130/37).

Comment: Finally, I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i've understood your question correctly, you are trying to convert the desired set of moments and total force which you calculated from a hypothetical pd controller into a set of forces. This is the relation that needs to be solved

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\
\mathbf{u}_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
0&L&0&-L\\
-L&0&L&0\\
\gamma&-\gamma&\gamma&-\gamma
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
F_1\\
F_2\\
F_3\\
F_4\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

where $u_1$ is the total force of all motors and $\mathbf{u}_2$ is the vector of moments acting on the system. This can simply be solved for by inverting this matrix. So
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
0&L&0&-L\\
-L&0&L&0\\
\gamma&-\gamma&\gamma&-\gamma
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\
\mathbf{u}_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
F_1\\
F_2\\
F_3\\
F_4\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}